# C# mvc 5 Data Annotation Restrict Numbers After Decimal point

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have model like

```
public class Invoice
{
    int  Invoice Number{get;set;}

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public float ReceivedAmount { get; set; }
}
```

In view Page, the `ReceivedAmount` is accepting many numbers after Dot like
500.25251, but I want 500.25

> It should prevent from entering the value in the field. Not show error message

Comment: it sounds to me like this is probably best handled through javascript

Comment: @user1666620 Give an example

Answer (score 1):

Accepting input as nothing to do with `[DisplayFormat()]` you can still add if you want but that's not it. What you need is a `[RegularExpression()]`

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$",ErrorMessage = "Price can't have more than 2 decimal places")]
public float ReceivedAmount { get; set; }
```

RegularExpressionAttribute Class: Specifies that a data field value in ASP.NET Dynamic Data must match the specified regular expression. - msdn

Answer (score 1):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$",ErrorMessage = "The Price cannot exceed 2 decimal places. Please Re-enter")]
public float ReceivedAmount { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:#.##}")]
   public float ReceivedAmount { get; set; }
```

Comment: The question is to only allow inputs with up to 2 decimal places. Your answer only shows outputs with 2 decimal places.

Comment: This property work for model whether it is input or output

Comment: its not working, it allows many numbers to enter